# Are all ARMs created equal?

Tags: arm, embedded, libraries

I have a toolchain from an older piece of hardware ([W315 from Moxa](https://www.moxa.com/en/products/phased-out-products/w315-series)), and when I run `file` on its library files, I get this:

```
[bf@localhost arm-linux-gnueabi]$ file /usr/local/arm-linux/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 
/usr/local/arm-linux/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (ARM), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

As you can see, this OpenSSL library is quite old and does not support TLSv1.2, which I need (at least). So I am trying to find an ARM binary of that library of a newer version. I have found 1.0.0 from Debian, but that has a little different signature:

```
[bf@localhost arm-linux-gnueabi]$ file libssl.so.1.0.0 
libssl.so.1.0.0: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=83c83f5d3da36759c7adc837405b28539569d26e, stripped
```

They are both 32 bit, and ELF, but I am not sure if the "ARM" part is comparable.

Could I use that 1.0.0 library in my application? And if not, what should I look for in searching for the right binary?

Results from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
root@Moxa:/home/fabs# cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor   : ARM922Tid(wb) rev 1 (v4l)
BogoMIPS    : 76.59
Features    : swp half thumb 
CPU implementer : 0x66
CPU architecture: 4
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0x526
CPU revision    : 1
Cache type  : VIVT write-back
Cache clean : cp15 c7 ops
Cache lockdown  : format B
Cache format    : Harvard
I size      : 16384
I assoc     : 2
I line length   : 16
I sets      : 512
D size      : 16384
D assoc     : 2
D line length   : 16
D sets      : 512

Hardware    : Moxa CPU development platform
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

Comment: You probably should cross-compile recent openssl (1.1.1k) for your target since  1.1.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.0 are not supported anymore. What is the output for command `uname -a` on your W315 system ?

Comment: @Frant `Linux Moxa 2.6.9-uc0 #4 Mon Jul 12 13:16:33 CST 2010 armv4tl unknown`. I think it will be tricky to build a more recent openssl.

Comment: Output for `cat /proc/cpuinfo` ? I will provide you with the proper procedure.

Comment: ARMs are definitely not created equal.  that says v4l but looks like it should be an armv5t.  you would need to insure the binary is made for something that old, and/or you have to re-compile it.  Unlikely your system has a cutting edge toolchain, recently support for armv4 was dropped (not sure about armv5), you likely have some time before worrying about that bit it could come into play and you would need to use an older gcc, like 8.x or 9.x or older. (quality of output got worse after 5.x.x in general)

Comment: even within the same architecture arms are not created equal.

Comment: @old_timer: it is even older I guess: ARMv4T...

Comment: @Bart Friederichs do you currently have a working cross-compiler for your target CPU ?

Comment: @Frant I assumed having a 900 number it was an arm9 which is armv5, but is what it is armv4t, you would definitely need to build for that

Comment: @old_timer: 100% agree. Remarks/suggestions on my answer are welcome: I used `-march=armv4t` and `-mcpu=arm922t`, what do you think ?

Comment: @old_timer ARM922T is an ARM9TDMI core part which is ARMv4T architecture.  You have to love ARMs numbering!  Not all ARM9 variants are V5 Architecture.  https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0184/b/introduction/about-the-arm922t

Comment: yep, gotta love it

Comment: @Frant yes. The toolchain that comes with the W315 (see link in question) comes with everything to build software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not. But You can build a recent/supported/secure version of openssl for your platform by using the following procedure:

```
# openssl
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz
tar zxf openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz

# a toolchain I know is working for arm922t according to gcc documentation
wget "https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-6/arm-linux-gnueabi/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz" -O gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz
mkdir -p /opt/arm/6
tar Jxf gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi.tar.xz -C /opt/arm/6

# building
cd openssl-1.1.1k
./Configure linux-generic32 --cross-compile-prefix=/opt/arm/6/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.1.1k --openssldir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1k
```

Edit the `Makefile`, and replace

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3
```

by:

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -O3 -march=armv4t -mcpu=arm922t
```

Then:

```
make install

ls -gG /opt/openssl-1.1.1k/bin/
    total 576
-rwxr-xr-x 1   6214 Jun 30 12:53 c_rehash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 579740 Jun 30 12:53 openssl

ls -gG /opt/openssl-1.1.1k/lib
    total 6432
drwxr-xr-x 2    4096 Jun 30 12:53 engines-1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 3312034 Jun 30 12:53 libcrypto.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      16 Jun 30 12:53 libcrypto.so -> libcrypto.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 2152072 Jun 30 12:53 libcrypto.so.1.1
-rw-r--r-- 1  603100 Jun 30 12:53 libssl.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1      13 Jun 30 12:53 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1  502704 Jun 30 12:53 libssl.so.1

file /opt/openssl-1.1.1k/bin/openssl
/opt/openssl-1.1.1k/bin/openssl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=7b0e69c478f4c7390d416247f95ac60d9a632bd8, with debug_info, not stripped
```

If needed, you can build a static version by adding the `-static` option at the end of the configuration command:

```
./Configure linux-generic32 --cross-compile-prefix=/opt/arm/6/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- --prefix=/opt/openssl-1.1.1k --openssldir=/opt/openssl-1.1.1k -static
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am getting there slowly, but when trying to compile my application using `/usr/local/arm-linux/bin/arm-linux-gcc -o helloworld libssl.a libcrypto.a helloworld.c`, I get an undefined reference on `SSL_library_init()`. Is the API different from 0.9.8?

Comment: Another issue seem to be that the binaries produced by this toolchain do not run on my device. (I get "file not found" when linked dynamically and "segmentation fault" when linked statically; even for a simple "Hello World" program).

Comment: I used my existing toolchain, and managed to build `.so` files. Copying them to the device, and doing some include file magic and I got it working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bart Friederichs: I would guess answer is yes for your `SSL_library_init()`-related question. I will download the toolchain and try to find out why gcc 6 cannot build executables for your system - this may have to do with the version of glibc your system is using.

Comment: No. The `SSL_library_init` call is defined in the `ssl.h` file. I was using the 0.9.8 headers to build with the 1.1.1k library. After I fixed that, it worked.